# knex seed not working in a docker environment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I'm using **nodejs** and **knex** for some REST apis. 
I use this code to run **migrations** and **seeds**

```
knex.migrate.latest()
.then(() => {
    return knex.seed.run();
})
.then(() => {
    // migrations are finished, init server

});
```

I'm using a **remote** **database** for this test. When I run it from **localhost** using `node index.js` it all runs fine, the migrations run and then the database is populated with seeds. However, when I create a **Docker** image and run it, the **migrations** work as expected but the **seeds** fail. The logs output is as follows:

```
Segmentation fault
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 139
npm ERR! com.app@0.2.0 start: `ENV=prod node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 139
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the com.app@0.2.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-12T12_20_43_664Z-debug.log
```

The problem is I can't get to the log file as the container imediatelly stops.

So, any suggestions on what's going on?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile? Do you map the application folder somewhere? How do your start the docker container? It looks like your `node_modules` folder has something not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

if the problem is that you cant get to see the log for further diagnose, maybe you can have a look at one of these [loging method](https://www.loggly.com/blog/top-5-docker-logging-methods-to-fit-your-container-deployment-strategy/)

Comment: Good source, 10x

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was a library not being installed correctly in the Docker image. The library is Bcrypt (I use it in the seed file to hash passwords for some permanent users). So I ended up changing `bcrypt` with `bryptjs` and now the docker image builds and runs correctly.